# Why there are processes with my userid after logout?

Tags: linux, debian, security, process

I am on a fairly standard Debian Sid system.

After logout, even after stopping the DM (LightDM, if it matters) I still see tons of processes running in my name.

I know I can have processes “detached” and resistant to `HANGUP`, but I didn't explicitly do anything like that.

Some of the processes I see are: `tracker-m`, `agent`, `evolution`, `gvfsd`, `applet.py`.

I cannot see *any* reason why they should continue running after I logoff.

Should I be concerned about system security?

Can someone explain?

Comment: How do you see those processes? Do you remain logged in via SSH? Are you checking from your own account or as pure root login?

Comment: @grawity: I switched to a text console (Ctrl-Alt-F1) and logged in as "root".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific processes you listed are normal – mostly GNOME components such as the file indexer, or the mail/calendar storage daemon. They *probably* should've exited, but the post doesn't contain enough information to answer whether the system was supposed to actively kill them off.

> I know I can have processes "detached" and resistant to HANGUP, but I didn't explicitly do anything like that.

The whole idea of "detaching" a process only applies if the process was attached to a terminal in the first place. None of your graphical session processes start this way; they never have a controlling terminal, and their input/output just goes to a logfile, if anywhere at all. As the hangup signal is generated when the controlling tty *disappears* (e.g. is literally "hung up"), having no controlling tty means none will be generated.

(Although even if you do start a process from a terminal, this doesn't prevent it from voluntarily "detaching" from that terminal (what is called 'daemonization'). Before integrated service managers such as launchd or systemd, all the background services like sshd or inetd would be launched from a terminal and detach themselves without being explicitly asked to.)

For the rough majority of your graphical session processes, a close equivalent might be the X server (Xorg). They might support an explicit "please exit" signal via SM, but generally, they just exit when Xorg exits and the connection to it is lost. But it's not a signal; it's voluntary on the part of the program, and sometimes the program doesn't immediately because it's busy doing something else and didn't notice.

A large part of your listed processes are actually daemons/services which don't even use X11. For example, gvfsd is the GNOME Virtual Filesystem daemon, which is normally only *used* by graphical programs, but is not X11-dependent on its own. Likewise, tracker-miner is the file indexing service – it doesn't use X11 at all. (But both happen to be D-Bus services, so they do the same when *dbus-daemon* exits and the bus connection is lost.)

Aside: Linux, traditionally, has had no system-wide concept of a "fully contained login session" until ... well, until systemd-logind started using cgroups to encapsulate session processes. Before that, having a stray process or two after logout was a common occurrence. Now if you configure logind to kill all user processes on logout, it will *kill* all user processes on logout.

However, it's not uncommon that the same daemon process would be shared between sessions of the same user – e.g. between a graphical session and an SSH login – so later logind versions shifted the focus from individual sessions to users. (In fact, systemd even brought in a new "user service" concept via 'systemctl --user'.) Now, even if you log out from GNOME or KDE, but still remain logged in via SSH, your processes won't be killed because you are still logged in! (This in particular affects the D-Bus services mentioned earlier: the bus is no longer specific to the graphical session, but is now shared for the entire user account.)

This last bit means that you'll only get useful results if you do the process check through a connection that's logged in directly as root (or some other user).

Comment: That is exactly what I did, as explained in the answer to Your comment. Could You please explain (or point me to relevant documentation) on how to setup logind so that it kills everybody pretending to be me? TiA! AFAIK X server is closed and restarted by LightDM between logins.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you should always be concerned about system security. So, irrespective of the rest of your question, that answer is yes.

There has been quite a discussion on whether all processes of a user should be terminated when the user logs out. Systemd developers thought it was a good idea, the rest of the world did not (a bit of simplification, but ..)

So now an explanation. When an interactive shell dies, it normally send a SIGHUP (SIGnal HangUP) to all its child processes. Unless the process has done something to handle it differently, SIGHUP terminates the children.

So, if the process has a handler to deal with the SIGHUP, it will do probably something else. Its parent process will normally become 1 (init on my Slackware).

Another option is that the process forks off a second process that does the actual work. The main process then dies. This is how many daemons work. The parent process is than already dead, so a SIGHUP will never go through to the forked-off daemon.

There are a number of reasons why a process should be kept running after you logout. For example: a mail client might continue to poll the mail server in your name so that, when you login again, your mailbox is up to date without the need of waiting for it.  A file system daemon might mount devices in your name. When there is a process still using that filesystem, the file system daemon may keep it mounted, even though that daemon may run under your name.

As for the specific processes: I don't know about `tracker-m`, `pplet.py` or `agent`. Could be anything, as far as I know. Probably some gnome stuff.

`evolution` is probably your mail client. Even tough it is not really necessary to run when you're logged out, it will reduce the start-up time of your mail client if it is kept running.

`gvfsd` is the Gnome virtual filesystem daemon.Keeping it running will allow you to keep, for example, USB disks mounted under your name.

So, in general, you may see processes in your name running after you logout. No problem with that. But, as a security aware person, you should investigate what is running.

Comment: Thanks Ljm, I understand, but things non't quite add-up: Among the processes "in my name" there was also systemd (some forked worker, I assume) and evolution, which was installed as part of gnome, but I NEVER used. I can understand this "let's help the user", but we are a bit too win-like here! I'm seriously thinking about removing Gnome, but I fear other desktops won't be much different :(

Comment: Removing Gnome will not prevent systemd to create processes in your name. If you want that, you must go to an non-systemd distribution (I use Salix, which is more or less the easy way to use Slackware). And yes, I moved from Fedora to Salix and one of the reasons was that systemd started all sorts of spurious processes (win-like).